# Bezier Curve - Cant select anchor points

Tags: bezier-curves

This is a really simple question but I am new to this.

I just started using blender on my Mac and I created a Bezier curve while following along with a tutorial.

I have toggled to edit mode, and am trying to select the endpoints in order to manipulate the curve. However, I am unable to click the endpoints to select them. I can rotate (using R) and move the curve (by pressing G) but I can't select the endpoints to drag them around[image] or the tangent lines.

Is there a quick fix for this? I am totally stuck :(

Thanks!

Comment: You can only select vertex and handles directly, not tangents or segments. Clicking on them should suffice. Why are there small numbers near your cursor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In blender select objects by **right mouse button** instead **left mouse button**. **Left mouse button** is used to place a 3d cursor.

If you want to change it - you can do this in **file** -> **user preferences** -> **input tab**. But it is recommended to stay as it is

Comment: Crantisz, thank you so much! I appreciate your help